# Is there a name for the graphs that R's corrplot library generates?

Tags: r, correlation, data-visualization

R's corrplot library can generate [some rather stimulating graphs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html):
[image]
[image]

I have an overpowered urge to see more of these, but I cannot find there name anywhere. What are they called? "corrplot" would be an obvious name, but I've only seen that name used as the title of the library. Even the earlier link does not appear to call the plots "corrplots".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these are called ***correlograms***. The term is used in multiple sources, including [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/correlogram.html), [here](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/correlogram/), and [here](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/correlograms.html). Note that in some sources, including Wikipedia, correlograms of this type are called corrgrams.